# git diff-files still returning files with space changes

Tags: git, diff

In my script, I am using `git diff-files -bw` to get a list of filenames which changed significantly (excluding whitespace).
This works, but then if a file has only whitespace changes and `git -P diff -bw` returns nothing, I still get that filename with `diff-files`. The output of this command is for example:

```
:100644 100644 6c639b47fd68f3b3461dd90f3ff1592dcdccea7a 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M      my-file
```

Is there a way for diff-files to truly ignore space changes?

EDIT: I also tried 'git -P diff --name-only -bw' and it returns the filename `my-file` while `git -P diff -bw` returns nothing!

Comment: `git diff-files` doesn't work like that. It is first and foremost a low-level helper that avoids any work at all cost. In the case where you do not ask for patch output, the tool does not even look at the file contents despite passing `-bw`. It looks only at the index metadata and from this it can derive that the files *are* different. Ask for patch output with `-bw -p` and it will report no changes.

Comment: @j6t, I see. I suspected something like this. Is there really no way to get a list of changed files while ignoring whitespace?

Comment: I don't recall that there is a way. I am afraid you have to script around `git diff-files -bw -p`.